# how to send ioctls to wifi driver using Android Apps

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am a system programmer,i put my apps in /system/priv-app and try to interact with the wifi driver.My code able to get the socket fd by adding INTERNET permission in the manifest file.

fd = sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

res = ioctl(fd,SIOCIWFIRSTPRIV,&buffer);

when executed this ioctl using JNI code is returning OPERATION NOT
PERMITTED as the error code.
But the same thing works when called using a c executable.
what should i do?

Thanks for first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this problem .
I send ioctls to WiFi driver by c program,and another Android Apps communicate with this c program by socket .